# Want to write a code to only send notification at certain time, but somehow the alarmManager is not working and it shows some errors

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

Not sending notification at selected time, when I ran my code, directly showed notification
and showed error as well
Here is the error message: E/NotificationManager: notifyAsUser: tag=null, id=12345, user=UserHandle{0}
I thought the error message was due to Build.VERSION.SDK_INT, but after adding that, the error message is still there.

Place all of these under onCreate:

```
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 13);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,9)
```

;

```
    Intent intent = new Intent ();
    intent.setAction("com.example.Broadcast");

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

//        PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0, intent,0);

```
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, contentIntent);
```

and here is the extend.

```
public class wakeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    setNotification(context);


}


protected void setNotification(Context context){

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0);

    String ChannelId = "12345";
    int uniID = 12345;

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,ChannelId )
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
            .setContentTitle("Hi")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setContentText("Please Rate.");


    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
```

//
        // Send notification to your device
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        builder.setChannelId("com.myApp");
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
                "com.myApp",
                "My App",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        );
        if (manager != null) {
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }
    manager.notify(uniID, builder.build());

}
```

}

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Please add the full exception text with stack trace to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are very confused.

In your code you call `NotificationManager.notify()`. This will show the `Notification` immediately.

You do:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0, intent,0);
```

This won't work. You have created a `PendingIntent` which will be sent via **broadcast** using an `Intent` that is for an `Activity`! What do you want to happen? Do you want an `Activity` to be launched or do you want a `BroadcastReceiver` to be triggered?

I think what you want to do is as follows:

- Create an `Intent` for a `BroadcastReceiver`, wrap that in a `PendingIntent` using `getBroadcast()` and pass that to the `AlarmManager` so that the broadcast `Intent` will be set at some future time.
- Create a class that `extends BroadcastReceiver`. In `onReceive()` create the `Notification` and call `NotificationManager.notify()` to post the `Notification`. In the `Notification` you can set a `PendingIntent` that opens your `Activity` so that if the user clicks on the `Notification` your `Activity` will be launched. To do this, call `PendingIntent.getActivity()` and pass an `Intent` that contains `MainActivity.class`.

Comment: Thank you very much David for helping me out. You were right, I was really confused. I just picked up Java and everything is new to me. Thank you for giving me guides on this. Following your steps,I have tired it but it's still working. Will update my code.

Comment: I looked at your updated code. How does Android know that it should start your `BroadcastReceiver`. The broadcast `Intent` you've created only has an ACTION. Please add your manifest declaration for `wakeReceiver` to the original question.